# What is the correct way to ask 'Do you know what I mean?' after you attempt to explain a thought?

Tags: grammar, politeness

I have recently started graduate school and a fellow student asks 'Do you know what I mean?' after nearly every statement they make.

I find it excruciatingly annoying, but I soon realized that I do the same thing by asking 'Does that make sense?' or something similar (though not nearly as frequently).

I now realize I might sound annoying to others if not condescending.  I am looking for a correct and polite way to ask someone if they understood what I said and if I was clear in articulating.  Does that make sense (joke)?

Really, I am looking for a way to give the person I am communicating with an easy and comfortable avenue to say 'You are not making sense' or 'I don't understand what you are saying' without giving the impression of 'I said it, is your puny mind capable of understanding what I said?'.

Comment: I can only offer this.  Your listener will give you indications long before they say anything that they do not follow you.  Pay attention to those little hints and you will never need to use any mannerism similar to "dyaknowwhatImeen?" that irritates you so much. People that say it to you probably aren't taking the time to notice how well you really are following what they are saying.

Comment: I do this, but very deliberately, and in a very specific context (I'm in tech sales for a living, and I often have to do a lot of presentations over the phone or web, where I don't get any nonverbal feedback, and I can't evaluate body language). It's a known trope in my industry that people in my position do this too frequently and rely on it as a crutch, or, in egregious cases, intentionally to discourage anyone raising objections, which would interfere with the sale (who wants be the 1 guy who says "I don't understand"?). So we're careful to vary how we ask, and phrase it to invite feedback.

Comment: "Have I managed to explain that reasonably clearly?"

Comment: Why would the person you're speaking with need to be prompted with a verbal cue by you?  Unless they give you a blank stare or a non-committal nod and "uh-huh", you'd have to assume they understood what you're saying, and if not, the onus is really on them to ask for clarification.  It sounds like a good idea to break that habit! :-)

Comment: @KristinaLopez In my experience, people are shy of explicitly expressing they haven't understood you, especially on a detailed or technical context where so expressing would make them appear (in their own mind, misguided or not) unintelligent. The problem is definitely exacerbated in the presence of others.  Kind of like a perverse conversational version of the [bystander effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bystander_effect). I'm sure schoolteachers encounter this problem frequently.

Comment: @DanBron - I provide medical software support so I'm well acquainted with a listener's reticence to admit they don't understand something.  I have to admit I rely heavily on follow-up e-mails with well-documented screenshots to back up my explanations.  I guess that would be the visual equivalent of "are you with me"?  lol!

Comment: "Does it makes sense?" is appropriate when trying to get across a relatively raw idea. I have hard time imagining a situation in which it would be condescending as you are opening a door to *you* not making sense and putting no weight on the receiver. In an informal communication with a fellow grad student on the topics you are well-familiar with and can present well, "Do you see this?"/ "Is this clear?" seem appropriate. "Do you know what I mean" is more appropriate when expressing an opinion and seeing if you've been understood - not if what you said makes sense/recognized as true.

Comment: It also can sometimes indicate that the speaker isn't sure he communicated effectively.  It also, as indicated above, can be habit or sincere.  I was the US liaison with the Indian office.  All thous guys would say was "sure sure".  AAAAA!  I did have to ask if the truly understood.  And I had to ask more than once.  Culture thing I guess.  And I might add the NEVER asked me.

Comment: In the interest of brevity, and a pop culture reference to Pirates of the Carribean, how about "..., savvy?"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Now that I think about it more, I appreciate it when one of the engineers I work for, when finishing a long, technical explanation, gives me a chance to ask for clarifications.  They say things like, **"Was any of that unclear?"** However, when it is habitually used as filler, as in the OP's opening scenario, that is when it turns into an irritation.

Comment: +1 for pointing out that it's *how* and *when* this kind of question is used, rather than how it is worded, that determines how annoying it is.

Answer (score 1):

There are any number of ways of asking this. The most important part to you, and them, is that as you do ask that it does not come across as the kind of repeated phrase you were first describing. I know people who end each sentence with "You know?" and it becomes part of the noise in the air. To respond to their question with an answer would confuse them completely.

You need to ask in a way that is not repetitious and not as a non-question. Whether it is "Am I clear?" or "Do you see?" it should just be one of a few phrases (non-repetitious) that you ask when you would actually like any answer they have.